# Is it possible to automatically output value in C# Interactive (REPL) like Immediate does?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, read-eval-print-loop, c#-interactive

I started using [C# Interactive](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx#Csharp) and like the fact that I can browse and explore some API functionalities like I do with `Immediate` without the need to run and debug my program.

The  problem is that it does not output the info like Immediate does unless I do a command with a variable name:

```
 > string.Format("{0,15}", 10m);         //hit enter, here there is no output
 > var a = string.Format("{0,15}", 10m); //hit enter so...
 > a                                     // hit enter and...
  "        10"                           //...here the value is shown
 >
```

Is there a way to make `C# Interactive` output the values in every evaluation like `Immediate` does (And without write more code for that like `Console.Write`)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, to output the result of an evaluated expression simply do not put a semicolon at the end. In your example, instead of this:

```
string.Format("{0,15}", 10m);
```

do this:

```
string.Format("{0,15}", 10m)
```

[See the documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window#evaluate)

Comment: Wow. How did I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

When you finish with a **statement** (e.g. ending with `;`), which you must when declaring variables, you don't get any output, as it's supposed to have side-effects only.

When you finish with an **expression** (e.g. not ending with `;`), you get the result of that expression.  A workaround is:

```
var a = string.Format("{0,15}", 10m); a
```

Notice `a` as an expression at the end, you'll get its value printed.

---

Personally, for multi-line snippets I want to test, I usually have a `res` variable:

```
object res;
// code where I set res = something;
using (var reader = new System.IO.StringReader("test"))
{
    res = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
res
```

The typing overhead happens once per Visual Studio session, but then I just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to select one of the previous entries.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. But the answer made by @Crowcoder is more like what I was looking for. Upvoted.

Comment: Ok, I now understand your question was simpler than stated.  I answered on the base that you intended to store the value in a variable and print it, instead of just printing it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is too late but anyone who is looking for an answer to similar question. Just in case you want to run a `for` loop and print values in C# interactive window, you can use `Print()` method:

```
string Characters = "Hello World!";
> foreach (char _Char in Characters)
. {
.     Print(_Char);
. }
'H'
'e'
'l'
'l'
'o'
' '
'W'
'o'
'r'
'l'
'd'
'!'
```

Comment: Wow!! This should be the accepted answer, I was searching for this for several months!!

Comment: Amazing! Where shall one get the docs for this `Print` function?

Comment: I can't find any documentation anywhere, I just found this accidentally :-)

Comment: ha ha!! an easter egg!!

Comment: thanks for writing this answer.
I was trying to print a long string which was being truncated by the C# interactive window.
But with this trick I could get the whole string!